# mysql multi table query return sort results before sending to view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm busy creating site to control the flow of documents. I have the following tables

Drawings
[image]

Drawing revision
[image]

Transmittal slip
[image]

Client
[image]

Project details[image]

In my site the user can select the documents that they want to send the client and to which clients it should be going to. The site should then present this in a view where the slip number, date, client and project info is presented once at the top of the page with the documents that are being sent to that client placed in a html table below this.

I created the following query.

```
SELECT tr.*, d.*, dr.*, cl.*, us.*, proj.project_name 
FROM transmittal_slips AS tr 
   INNER JOIN drawings AS d ON tr.dwg_id = d.dwg_id 
   INNER JOIN dwg_rev AS dr ON d.dwg_id = dr.dwg_id 
   INNER JOIN client AS cl ON tr.client_id = cl.client_id 
   INNER JOIN `user` AS us ON tr.user_id = us.id 
   INNER join projects AS proj ON tr.project_no = proj.project_no 
 WHERE tr.slip_num = '".$slip_num."' AND dr.slip_num = '".$slip_num."'   
 ORDER BY cl.client_id"
```

My query joins all the tables and in Codeigniter gives it back to me a numeric array which I can pass to the view, but which I would then need to filter the array to get the display I want as described above.

This is the current display that is produced with a `foreach` loop and some  tags and an html table.
[image]

This is the way that I want the data displayed.
[image]

How do I filter or sort the results per client before passing it to the view so I can get the view to display the slip number, date, client info, etc once with the documents listed below this. I suppose you could compare what I want to do to an invoice from an online store such as amazon.

**Please help somebody**

Comment: can you post expected output as well??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have some header information that is the same for all rows, and then some data that is different for each row. If you want to be formal about it, after the query, you can do something like:

```
$header = rows[0];
$list = array_map(function($row) { return array('dwg_id' => $row->dwg_id, ...); }, $rows);
```

but really all you need to do in the view is first render your header based on a single row, then loop through all the rows and cherry-pick the fields you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not quite sure how I would go about using an array_map. I'm still a novice at php. Your right that I would need to extract the header once and the rest I'll need to run trough. I'm not quite sure how to actually do this...

Comment: array_map takes one array, does something to each item in it, and returns another array. so if your query returns an array called $rows, you can use array_map to build another array with a subset of the items. The function above just creates a new row with only the desired fields of the original.

Comment: Thanks. Managed to get the array_map to work. But your code does contain some syntax errors. Here is the code that worked for me. `$data['list'] = array_map("modify_array", $data['results']);
function modify_array($row) 
{ 
 return array('dwg_id' => $row['dwg_id'],... ); 
};`

Comment: The other solution I managed to work out was to use a `while` loop in a `foreach` loop. Everything for the header is placed in the `while` loop so it loops once. The rest is just echoed normal by the `foreach` loop. `foreach($results as $row)
{
 while($index<1)
 {
  echo $row['slip_num'] ;
  $index++;
 }
 echo $row['sws_dwg_no'];
 echo $row['dwg_title'] ;
 }`

Comment: Dang. If I could change one thing about php it would be to make the order of arguments more consistent between functions in the same family. Updated my code sample. I think your `while(index<1){...}` could be replaced by a simpler-to-read `if index == 1{...}`